# python group by column and select by hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe such as:

```
col-a   col-b
1       None
1       Failed
1       Passed
2       None
2       Passed
3       Inconclusive
3       Passed
```

and a hierarchy of terms:

```
Failed > Inconclusive > Passed > None
```

How can I get something like:

```
1       Failed
2       Passed
3       Inconclusive
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary for column created by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then sorting by both columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and get first unique row per groups by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
d = {'Failed':0,'Inconclusive':1, 'Passed':2, None: 3}
df['new'] = df['col-b'].map(d)
df = df.sort_values(['col-a', 'new']).drop_duplicates('col-a').drop('new', 1)
print (df)
   col-a         col-b
1      1        Failed
4      2        Passed
5      3  Inconclusive
```

Another idea with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html):

```
d = {'Failed':0,'Inconclusive':1, 'Passed':2, None: 3}
df =  df.loc[df['col-b'].map(d).groupby(df['col-a']).idxmin()]
print (df)
   col-a         col-b
1      1        Failed
4      2        Passed
5      3  Inconclusive
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {'Failed':1, 'Inconclusive': 2, 'Passed':3, 'None':4}

(
    df.assign(b=df['col-b'].map(h))
    .groupby(by='col-a')
    .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by=['b']).head(1))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .drop('b',1)
)

col-a   col-b
0   1   Failed
1   2   Passed
2   3   Inconclusive
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

- [`DataFrame.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) - Drop specified labels from rows or columns.
- [`GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) - Compute first of group values.
- [`DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - Reset the index, or a level of it.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col-a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
               'col-b': ['None','Failed','Passed','None','Passed','Inconclusive','Passed']})

df = df.drop(df[df['col-b'] == 'None'].index).groupby('col-a').first().reset_index()
# or
# m = df['col-b'].apply(lambda x: x == 'None')
# df = df[~m].groupby('col-a').first().reset_index()
print(df)
```

**or mask and groupby, if None is class NoneType.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col-a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
               'col-b': [None,'Failed','Passed',None,'Passed','Inconclusive','Passed']})
m = df['col-b'].apply(lambda x: x is None)
df = df[~m].groupby('col-a').first().reset_index()
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
   col-a         col-b
0      1        Failed
1      2        Passed
2      3  Inconclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` if i right understand question.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col-a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'col-b': [None,'Failed','Passed',None,'Passed','Inconclusive','Passed']})

df['rang'] = df['col-b'].map({'Failed':1, 'Passed':2, 'Inconclusive':3})
```

df:

```
    col-a   col-b        rang
0   1       None         NaN
1   1       Failed       1.0
2   1       Passed       2.0
3   2       None         NaN
4   2       Passed       2.0
5   3       Inconclusive 3.0
6   3       Passed       2.0
```